# Two threads getting same value

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning multithreading.

Below is small code snippet

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class UnsafeSequence {

    private int value;

    public int getNext() {

        return value++;

    }
}
```

I want to know, When and how `two different threads` could get same `value` ? Any scenario, please share ?

Comment: Java has a very cleanly defined model for multithreading and is a good language to learn the basics. You will want to read about _happens-before_, which is the technical way that interactions are defined. The rules are very specific and can seem very picky, but they are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
UnsafeSequence seq = new UnsafeSequence();

new Thread(() -> System.out.println(seq.getNext())).start();
new Thread(() -> System.out.println(seq.getNext())).start();
```

Easy enough. This has the possibility to print the same number. Why?

`value++` gets desugared to `value = value + 1`

Say that `Thread 1` reads value as 0, and and adds 1 to it but doesn't assign it back to `value` yet. At the same time, `Thread 2` reads the value as 0 and adds 1 to it. Now, just like that, we have a race condition and `1` is printed out twice.

You can solve this problem with `AtomicInteger`

```
public class Safe {

    private AtomicInteger value;

    public int getNext() {

        return value.getAndIncrement();

    }
}
```

Now, this is safe and will never print the same number twice

Comment: but the moment its got incremented, Isn't assigned the new value to "value" ? And new "value will be used by next thread. Nope ? I'm sorry but your answer bit confusing to me ..!

Comment: @Maria No, not "the moment". These are all separate "moments": When the value in the execution stack is incremented, when that value is written to the field, and when the new value in the field is updated for the other threads to read.

Comment: @Maria Without a _happens-before_ relationship, a write to `value` by one thread is not guaranteed to be seen by any other thread. On top of that, the post-increment operation is not atomic and is actually three different operations: Read the current value from `value`, add one to that value, and finally write the new value back to `value`. That means, even when ignoring the memory visibility issues, different threads could read and increment the same value, thus getting the same result.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-, you mean to say value's incrementation itself goes under one process, For ex: pick value to be incremented, increment it and then asign back to variable who is holding it.  And value will remain old until this process is compelted. And when during incrementaion process started by T1 is not finished, T2 will get the old value only but not the new one which is under processing. Correct ..?

Comment: @Maria That is the most common way this can be wrong, yes.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-, Is there any way I could track down the process (steps happening internally) which is being done to increment a value ?

Comment: Use `javap` to disassemble the `.class` file into bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

`value++` is not an `atomic operation` (which means not a single, indivisible operation).

Behind `value++` is hidden 3 operations (read-modify-write) ->

```
int temp = value;
temp = temp + 1;
value = temp;
```

With some unlucky timing 2 threads can read the old value (`int temp = value`) and so generate a `lost update` -> 2 increment giving the same final value.

This is called a `race condition` because the result of the operation depends on the scheduling and interleaving of multiple threads by the runtime.

This sequence of operations need to be atomic and to do so you have to use some synchronization mechanisms.

Exemple of "some" solutions :

A. Use atomic variables (from `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package). Best approach in this example

B. Use intrinsic lock (`synchronized`)

```java
@ThreadSafe
public class SafeSequence {

    private int value;

    public synchronized int getNext() {

        return value++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Even without the split logic (which is correct), without using `volatile` or `synchronized` there's no reason to trust that thread 2 will see the value written by thread 1 _ever_.

Comment: ok you're talking about `a = 2` for instance and the fact that we need to make  `a` volatile to avoid only the modification "happened" at thread stack memory only and  therefore thread 2 seeing previous value.

Comment: @CodeScale, Using Atomic Value prevent to be accessed by another thread if its being under processed itself by another thread ?

Comment: using atomic variable insures atomic state transitions on numbers and references. As `AtomicLong` is thread-safe and your code is depending only to  this thread-safe state..your  code becomes thread-safe too.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know, When and how two different threads could get same value ? Any scenario, please share ?

The premise behind this question is dangerously wrong. The premise is that unless someone can think of a way that something can happen, you can conclude that it can't happen. This is dangerously wrong.

We have standards and rules that tell us what behavior we can rely on it. When they tell us we can't rely on things, then we can't rely on those things. It doesn't matter whether we can think of a way it can fail. You are never going to be clever enough to think of every possible way that something can fail.

Even if nobody can think of a way something can fail today, future CPUs, future compilers, future JVM implementations may do things that we can't think of today. The standards provide us specific guarantees so that we don't have to worry about what future optimizations or implementations might do.

You have several other answers that imagine specific ways that this could fail. But they aren't the actual answer to your question because the answer is precisely the same whether or not anyone can think of a way that something can fail -- the relevant standards don't say this can't happen, therefore it can. You can only rely on the guarantees you actually have.